# Getting callback from one API to other API with help of POST method in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

I'm writing api1 and need to get a callback from api2 to api1, I'll get a response from api2, this api2 response I'll use in api1 how could I do that in AWS lambda function..?

the thing here is I'm developing an food delivery app with backend Python in AWS lambda function, if a user is ordering something from app, shop owner and delivery staff will accept the order here shop owner will be one and he accepts the order, but there will be number of delivery staff so there is problem for me. if 1st delivery staff is rejecting the order to deliver how will I get the response from the api2 from the current api1 which api1 I will run at that time. I think I need cron jobs for this..?

Comment: I think this question would benefit from a diagram with a Flowchart to make clear what you're trying to achieve/asking about. What have you built and which part of the flow are you struggling with?